# Search Query to Filter Results in React

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I'm trying to filter data based on a simple user search input.

I'm not sure if its the way i'm filtering the data, but whenever I input something in the text box, the data disappears.  I can see in dev tools that the state of the query is being stored.

Here's my code in my context file. I'm planning on adding additional filters once the search function is fixed, thus the reason for the more complicated code.

```
    import * as React from "react";

const DefaultState = {
  cardListings: [],
  filter: {}
};

const CardListingsContext = React.createContext(DefaultState);

export const CardListingsConsumer = CardListingsContext.Consumer;

export class CardListingsProvider extends React.Component {
  static applyFilter(cards, filter) {
    const { query } = filter;
    let result = cards;
    if (query) {
      const search = query.toLowerCase();
      result = result.filter(item => item.title.indexOf(search) !== -1);
    }
    return result;
  }

  state = DefaultState;

  componentDidMount() {
    fetch("http://localhost:9000/mwBase")
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(res => {
        this.setState({ cardListings: res });
      });
  }

  updateFilter = filter => {
    this.setState({
      filter
    });
  };

  render() {
    const { children } = this.props;
    const { cardListings, filter } = this.state;

    const filteredListings = CardListingsProvider.applyFilter(
      cardListings,
      filter
    );

    return (
      <CardListingsContext.Provider
        value={{
          allListings: cardListings,
          cardListings: filteredListings,
          updateFilter: this.updateFilter
        }}
      >
        {children}
      </CardListingsContext.Provider>
    );
  }
}
```

Here's my input form

```
<form
      className={formClasses}
      noValidate
      onChange={() =>
        setTimeout(() => this.props.updateFilter(this.state), 0)
      }
    >
      <p className="mb-1">Refine your results</p>
      <div className="form-group">
        <input
          type="text"
          className="form-control form-control-lg"
          placeholder="Search for a card..."
          name="query"
          value={this.state.query}
          onChange={event => this.setState({ query: event.target.value })}
        />
      </div>
```

and where the Filter is being applied on my home page:

```
<CardListingsProvider>
          <CardListingsConsumer>
            {function(value) {
              const { cardListings, updateFilter } = value;
              return (
                <>
                  <Filter updateFilter={updateFilter} />
                  <div className="columns">
                    {cardListings.map(item => (
                      <Card key={item.itemId} card={item} />
                    ))}
                  </div>
                </>
              );
            }}
          </CardListingsConsumer>
        </CardListingsProvider>
              </div>
```

Here's example of my dataset:

```
   [
{
itemId: [
"120901386991"
],
title: [
"1952 Topps Mickey Mantle Chase Card Box 18 packs 5 1950s or 1960's cards per box"
],
globalId: [
"EBAY-US"
],
subtitle: [
"3 BX LOT. 1 VINTAGE PK PER 25 BOXES* LOOK 4 1952 MANTLE"
],
primaryCategory: [
{
categoryId: [
"213"
],
categoryName: [
"Baseball Cards"
]
}
],
secondaryCategory: [
{
categoryId: [
"156521"
],
categoryName: [
"Vintage Non-Sport Cards"
]
}
],
galleryURL: [
"https://thumbs4.ebaystatic.com/m/m1mtMB65mAApWQ2EhJy4qWA/140.jpg"
],
viewItemURL: [
"https://rover.ebay.com/rover/1/711-53200-19255-0/1?ff3=2&toolid=10044&campid=5338164673&customid=watchbask&lgeo=1&vectorid=229466&item=120901386991"
],
paymentMethod: [
"PayPal"
],
autoPay: [
"true"
],
location: [
"USA"
],
country: [
"US"
],
shippingInfo: [
{
shippingServiceCost: [
{
@currencyId: "USD",
__value__: "0.0"
}
],
shippingType: [
"Free"
],
shipToLocations: [
"Worldwide"
],
expeditedShipping: [
"false"
],
oneDayShippingAvailable: [
"false"
],
handlingTime: [
"1"
]
}
],
sellingStatus: [
{
currentPrice: [
{
@currencyId: "USD",
__value__: "118.0"
}
],
convertedCurrentPrice: [
{
@currencyId: "USD",
__value__: "118.0"
}
],
sellingState: [
"Active"
],
timeLeft: [
"P10DT14H59M31S"
]
}
],
listingInfo: [
{
bestOfferEnabled: [
"false"
],
buyItNowAvailable: [
"false"
],
startTime: [
"2012-04-23T16:52:17.000Z"
],
endTime: [
"2019-10-23T16:52:17.000Z"
],
listingType: [
"FixedPrice"
],
gift: [
"false"
],
watchCount: [
"443"
]
}
],
returnsAccepted: [
"false"
],
condition: [
{
conditionId: [
"1000"
],
conditionDisplayName: [
"Brand New"
]
}
],
isMultiVariationListing: [
"false"
],
pictureURLLarge: [
"https://i.ebayimg.com/00/s/NTAwWDMxNA==/z/sT8AAOSw62VZv9qQ/$_1.JPG"
],
topRatedListing: [
"false"
]
},
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case title is an array of string. If it is supposed to contain only one element. You can change your filter function from

```
result.filter(item => item.title.indexOf(search) !== -1);
```

to

```
result.filter(item => item.title[0].indexOf(search) !== -1);
```

If the title array contains multiple items, You could do use `Array.some`

```
result.filter(item =>
  item.title.some(eachTitle => {
    return eachTitle.indexOf(search) !== -1
  })
)
```

And if you need case insensitive filter, you might need to change the filter function on that aspect too.

```
const search = query.toLowerCase();
result.filter(item => item.title[0].toLowerCase().indexOf(search) !== -1);
```

Looks like the code snippet you have posted might not be complete. I see some unbalanced parentheses for `applyFilter` Function in your Provider component.

```
  static applyFilter(cards, filter) {
    const { query } = filter;
    let result = cards;
    if (query) {
      const search = query.toLowerCase();
      result = result.filter(item => item.title.indexOf(search) !== -1);
    }

  state = DefaultState;
```

Also I'm wondering why would you need a `setTimeout` to call `setState` function in `Filter` component. The below

```
onChange={() =>
          setTimeout(() => this.props.updateFilter(this.state), 0)
        }
```

You can get rid of that as well.

I have made some edits to complete `applyFilter` function to return the filtered data. Please have a look at the below code and `Run Code Snippet` to see the code in action. Hope this helps!

```js
// Provider Class

const DefaultState = {
  cardListings: [],
  filter: {}
};

const CardListingsContext = React.createContext(DefaultState);

const CardListingsConsumer = CardListingsContext.Consumer;

class CardListingsProvider extends React.Component {
  static applyFilter(cards, filter) {
    const {
      query
    } = filter;
    let result = cards;
    if (query) {
      const search = query.toLowerCase();
      result = result.filter(item => item.title[0].toLowerCase().indexOf(search) !== -1);
    }
    return result;
  }

  state = DefaultState;

  componentDidMount() {
    Promise.resolve([
  {
    itemId: ['1'],
    title: ['Apple']
  },
  {
    itemId: ['2'],
    title: ['Orange']
  },
  {
    itemId: ['3'],
    title: ['Peach']
  }
]).then(res => {
      this.setState({
        cardListings: res
      });
    });
  }

  updateFilter = filter => {
    this.setState({
      filter
    });
  };

  render() {
    const {
      children
    } = this.props;
    const {
      cardListings,
      filter
    } = this.state;

    const filteredListings = CardListingsProvider.applyFilter(
      cardListings,
      filter
    );

    return ( <
      CardListingsContext.Provider value = {
        {
          allListings: cardListings,
          cardListings: filteredListings,
          updateFilter: this.updateFilter
        }
      } >
      {
        children
      } 
      </CardListingsContext.Provider>
    );
  }
}



class Filter extends React.Component {
  state = { query: "" };
  render() {
    return (
      <form
        noValidate
        onChange={() =>
          setTimeout(() => this.props.updateFilter(this.state), 0)
        }
      >
        <p className="mb-1">Refine your results</p>
        <div className="form-group">
          <input
            type="text"
            className="form-control form-control-lg"
            placeholder="Search for a card..."
            name="query"
            value={this.state.query}
            onChange={event => this.setState({ query: event.target.value })}
          />
        </div>
      </form>
    );
  }
}




class Home extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <CardListingsProvider>
          <CardListingsConsumer>
            {function(value) {
              const { cardListings, updateFilter } = value;
              return (
                  <React.Fragment>
                  <Filter updateFilter={updateFilter} />
                  <div className="columns">
                    {cardListings.map(item => (
                      <div key={item.itemId}>{JSON.stringify(item)}</div>
                    ))}
                  </div>
                  </React.Fragment>
              );
            }}
          </CardListingsConsumer>
        </CardListingsProvider>
      </div>
    );
  }
}





ReactDOM.render( <Home /> , document.getElementById("root"))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: hey thanks for your help on this.  I looked over all your code and aside from changing a few of the functions into class based components, i don't see anything different.  what exactly did you change?  sorry, if i'm not seeing it

Comment: The first code snippet you have posted (CardListingsProvider) gives syntax error due to unbalanced parentheses. Fixed that and everything works!!

Comment: yeah, looks like i copied code in incorrectly, just fixed.  thus, i'm testing my site, and the data loads normally on mount, the allListings and cardListings data are populated (in dev console) and if a user enters text, the cardListings data goes blank even if there is a match.  Thus for some reason the filter isn't working on my data.

Comment: Make sure the data is matching as per the mock data I pasted in my code. That could be the possible reason. I looked at the filter function and created a mock state structure

Comment: i added example of my dataset, totally stumped here

Comment: Looks like dataset structure is different.